# Вложенные списки Haskell

Tags: список, списки, haskell

Нужно достать слово "STUDENT" из многоуровневого списка.

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
let list2 = tail ( tail [["4110"],["GROUP OF"],["STUDENT","IVANOV",["ALEXEY"]]])
print (head list2)
```

Ругается на ["ALEXEY"].

> prog.hs:3:69: error:
>       • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
>       • In the expression: "ALEXEY"
>       • In the expression: ["ALEXEY"]
>       • In the expression: ["STUDENT", "IVANOV", ["ALEXEY"]]

Comment: А как ругается-то? Добавьте в вопрос (кнопка `править`) описание ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список не может содержать элементы разного типа, т.е. в данном случае одновременно содержать строки и список строк.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.